# ES module imports - can it always be done? A failed example trying to import socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, socket.io, es6-modules, preact

I'm trying to use a "build-less" process so I'm using a plain module `script` in an html file (following the Preact docs):

```
<script type="module">
  import {
    html,
    render,
  } from 'https://unpkg.com/htm/preact/index.mjs?module';
 
  function App(props) {
    return html`<h1>Hello ${props.name}!</h1>`;
  }

  render(html`<${App} name="world" />`, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

I'm able to get the client socket.io working if I by-pass the module system and rely on the `window` global (note: I'm serving the html file from an http server that's been passed to socket.io's server and have `/socket.io/socket.io.js` automatically installed):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<!-- in previous module script: -->
  const socket = window.io();

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('socket id>>', socket.id);
  });
```

I would like to import the socket.io client from an ES module. I know I could encapsulate the `window` use in my own JS file and then import that in the module script in my html, but I'm trying to do this instead and it isn't working:

```
  import io from '/socket.io.js'; // after copying socket.io.js to my public dir
  import { io } from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/engine.io-client/3.5.0/engine.io.js'; // I have tried several variations of urls and what is imported
```

Judging by:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/socket.io.js' does not
> provide an export named 'default'

and by the "polyfill"ed (if that's the correct term) commonjs globals like `module` in the probably-webpack bundle which is `socket.io.js` - it is likely that there just is no support for ES modules for this library.

I will probably be facing this issue over and over so I have decided to go back to having a build step.

My question is - is there a way around this "3rd party libraries not supporting ES module imports out of the box"? Maybe with a little work on my part I can get around this and try completing a small project without a build step in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way around this "3rd party libraries not supporting ES module imports out of the box"?

Unfortunately no, at least not always. It is impossible for a browser to natively `import` something that is not an ES module. However, if you've got access to the original source code, and the source code itself is written as an ES module (and then transpiled/bundled), you can sometimes build ES modules out of it yourself.

In the case of socket.io, [their repo](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) hosts the source code in TypeScript, which makes use of `import`/`export`. Unfortunately, their code also makes use of `require()` and other npm packages, which ultimately means it cannot be trivially converted to an ES module.

Comment: Fair enough - I thought that might be the case. Can't wait for deno to get more traction. Thanks!